# CSS3 Animation not working in Mozilla

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I've read other answers for the same question in stackoverflow, but I couldn't solve it with them.

My code doesn't work in mozilla, can anyone help me?

Besides that, Can anyone tell me the correct way to use @keyframes. I mean, is it correct to use @-webkit-keyframes, @-moz-keyframes and @keyframes, or with only one it should be fine?

Thanks

```
header .resaltar {
    color: #F3D85E;
    font-weight: bold;
}
header .resaltar:hover {
    -webkit-animation: shake 0.8s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: shake 0.8s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: shake 0.8s linear infinite;
    animation: shake 0.8s linear infinite;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
/** Chrome, Safari, Opera **/
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    20% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
    30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    70% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    90% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}

 @-moz-keyframes shake {
    0% { -moz-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -moz-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    20% { -moz-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
    30% { -moz-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    40% { -moz-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    50% { -moz-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    60% { -moz-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    70% { -moz-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
    80% { -moz-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    90% { -moz-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -moz-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}

@keyframes shake {
    0% { transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
    30% { transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    70% { transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
    80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    90% { transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
```

Comment: Works for me on Firefox 34.0.5. My guess is there is a mistake in your `header .resaltar` selector. Can't be 100% sure without seeing your html.

Comment: Hello TreeTree. The whole html is very large, but this exact effect is <span class="resaltar">happen</span>.

Comment: Is the first set of css properties working, as in is the text bold and yellow?

Comment: please make a jsfiddle , add your html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem you are having is animation to a span element.
i noticed that if u apply this animation to the parent element (the header) it works fine.

I think your problem is that the display of the span is inline
Once i changed the display to inline-block, it worked fine with me

```
header .resaltar {
    color: #F3D85E;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hello MrByte11, applying inline-block to the span made it work on Mozilla, thanks! But I don't understand why it happen...Why does it work now?

Comment: it didn't make a lot of sense to me either... I figured it out after trying the animation on a different element ( the div instead of the span). And after comparing them i noticed it s a display issue.

Comment: I read somewhere that an inline element is not a "transformable element" hence u can't apply animations to it, but it doesn't make sense since it works fine on Chrome (but not on Safari or Mozilla)